# Changing locale on a per app basis in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, internationalization

Our organisation in ArcGIS Online is localised to a non-english language. I'm now working on a project aimed at english speaking visitors.
As such, I want to change the localisation for the Web Map Application for this specific project.

Is it possible to change the localisation of the AGOL GUI for a specific web map app, without changing the localisation for our entire organisation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your creating apps with AppBuilder (either the embedded one in ArcGIS Online, or the Developer edition), you can make [use of a URL parameter](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/manage-apps/app-url-parameters.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_4C835BF50CDA43BFB576627CBAF18853) to change the language of the app.

> To switch app language, use locale=. These language
>   codes are supported:
>   ar,cs,da,de,en,el,es,et,fi,fr,he,it,ja,ko,lt,lv,nb,nl,pl,pt-br,pt-pt,ro,ru,sv,th,tr,zh-cn,vi,zh-hk,zh-tw.
>
> For example
>
> http:///apps/webappviewer/index.html?locale=fr

If you are building custom widgets for AppBuilder, you will have to [factor in other languages](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/add-i18n-support.htm) in your code.

I believe the language URL parameter might also work on some of the other templates applications as well.

For an ArcGIS Online for Organisation, the Admin can set the language for the site.  However, as a named user, if your browser uses a different language, you will see that language. You can also override the organisations language you see by [updating your individual profile.](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/set-language-region.htm)

Hope that helps.